# How do I remove the word "Blog" from a WordPress Homepage?

Tags: templates

[image]

I would like to remove the word "Blog" from this WordPress homepage. It is existing within the selected theme. Where in the Theme Editor code should I look to find and delete this text? The theme is Catch Vogue.

Answer (score 1):

The file where you could delete the text is `index.php`

This is the line containing the text, so you could remove this line.
`<h2 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Blog', 'catch-vogue' ); ?></h2>`

For future reference, if you were to update the theme at a later date when an update becomes available from the theme author, the file will be overwritten and you would lose the change you made. To avoid this you can look at creating a child theme to make your changes, so that you can update the theme in the future without losing any modifications you may have made.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/